# Pandas - What is the benefit / use case of the parameter dummy_na in the function get_dummies()?

Tags: python, pandas

Following the Pandas documentation:

```
>>> s1 = ['a', 'b', np.nan]

>>> pd.get_dummies(s1)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0

>>> pd.get_dummies(s1, dummy_na=True)
   a  b  NaN
0  1  0    0
1  0  1    0
2  0  0    1
```

Now, I don't understand why would someone need to use Dummy_na, nor I've found any comment regarding this on stackoverflow.

As someone who works in Data Science, I wonder if there is any kind of benefit in marking NaNs values in this way

Comment: It could be a feature, when you do not have data for something. For example color could be red, green or you do not have data for it.

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko Indeed. But the fact that you are not Red, and not Green, already implies that you have no data for it

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your example, the third item has neither of the values. This is a valuable feature as well. For example, if each feature is a disease a patient have you might want to know that a patient does not have any disease.

Comment: I think this is not enough of a reason: if you say "for each disease, you result negative" you are already communicating that the patient has no disease... The information is already implicit. What would be the use case for expliciting it?